# Instagram's like Video effect for Android

Tags: android, video, instagram, video-processing

I'm making an application in which video is editable at run time like Instagram:

Below is the links for iOS frameworks:

1) https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder

2) https://github.com/rFlex/CoreImageShop

Is there any framework available like this for Android in which effects can be applied on videos at run time.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31958741/1118886)

Comment: @Irfan did you found something for this?

Comment: @SanjayHirani yes my issue was solved by upper comment by sheraz: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805837/applying-effects-on-video-being-played/31958741#31958741

Comment: were you able to save that video after applying filter?

Comment: @irfan If you can help me to know how you saved that video, it would be of great help.

Comment: @SherazAhmadKhilji please help out Sanjay Hirani, Thanks.

Comment: @SanjayHirani At the end i implemented video saving wit effects using FFMPEG or Open CV library so you better look at them. I am sorry but videffects doesn't currently support saving effects on video and that is something that i still have to do.

Comment: @SherazAhmadKhilji I am looking for Video filter similar to Instagram app i.e. Filters are applied while video is playing. So ffmpeg does not help as it takes time. Does Open CV has this type of facility to apply filters?

Comment: @SanjayHirani i believe that can is something being done using NDK. If you want something like that then i suggest one way would be using NDK or forking videffects and adding that feature in it. I don't know how much of that is possible using Open Cv as i haven't done it since quite a while.