# Applying Effects on Video being Played

Tags: android, video, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I am new to the world of Open Gl and I have googled a lot but i am unable to find a way to implement [Effects](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html) on a video being played. After some research i have finally found a [class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14999912/1118886) that can be used to play video on a GLSurfaceView. And i know from [Google documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/package-summary.html) and that we can apply effects on a video.

By following this [post](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-android-media-effects-with-opengl-es--cms-23650) i was able to successfully apply effects on bitmaps. Now i want to do that for my video so any help or pointers is appreciated.

[Here](https://github.com/crossle/MediaPlayerSurface/blob/master/src/me/crossle/demo/surfacetexture/VideoSurfaceView.java) is the VideoSurfaceView that i am using to Render Video that is being played

```
package me.crossle.demo.surfacetexture;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;

@SuppressLint("ViewConstructor")
class VideoSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    VideoRender mRenderer;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

    public VideoSurfaceView(Context context, MediaPlayer mp) {
        super(context);

        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mMediaPlayer = mp;
        mRenderer = new VideoRender(context);
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        queueEvent(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    mRenderer.setMediaPlayer(mMediaPlayer);
                }});

        super.onResume();
    }

    private static class VideoRender
        implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer, SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener {
        private static String TAG = "VideoRender";

        private static final int FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4;
        private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES = 5 * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;
        private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET = 0;
        private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET = 3;
        private final float[] mTriangleVerticesData = {
            // X, Y, Z, U, V
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 0.f, 0.f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 1.f, 0.f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 0.f, 1.f,
            1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 1.f, 1.f,
        };

        private FloatBuffer mTriangleVertices;

        private final String mVertexShader =
                "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
                "uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;\n" +
                "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
                "attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
                "  vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;\n" +
                "}\n";

        private final String mFragmentShader =
                "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
                "precision mediump float;\n" +
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
                "}\n";

        private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
        private float[] mSTMatrix = new float[16];

        private int mProgram;
        private int mTextureID;
        private int muMVPMatrixHandle;
        private int muSTMatrixHandle;
        private int maPositionHandle;
        private int maTextureHandle;

        private SurfaceTexture mSurface;
        private boolean updateSurface = false;

        private static int GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES = 0x8D65;

        private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

        public VideoRender(Context context) {
            mTriangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                mTriangleVerticesData.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES)
                    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
            mTriangleVertices.put(mTriangleVerticesData).position(0);

            Matrix.setIdentityM(mSTMatrix, 0);
        }

        public void setMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer player) {
            mMediaPlayer = player;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (updateSurface) {
                    mSurface.updateTexImage();
                    mSurface.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix);
                    updateSurface = false;
                }
            }

            GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
            checkGlError("glUseProgram");

            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);

            mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
            checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
            checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");

            mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
            checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
            checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");

            Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);

            GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
            checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
            GLES20.glFinish();

        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
            mProgram = createProgram(mVertexShader, mFragmentShader);
            if (mProgram == 0) {
                return;
            }
            maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
            checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aPosition");
            if (maPositionHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aPosition");
            }
            maTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTextureCoord");
            checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aTextureCoord");
            if (maTextureHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aTextureCoord");
            }

            muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
            checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uMVPMatrix");
            if (muMVPMatrixHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uMVPMatrix");
            }

            muSTMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uSTMatrix");
            checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uSTMatrix");
            if (muSTMatrixHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uSTMatrix");
            }


            int[] textures = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);

            mTextureID = textures[0];
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);
            checkGlError("glBindTexture mTextureID");

            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                                   GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                                   GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

            /*
             * Create the SurfaceTexture that will feed this textureID,
             * and pass it to the MediaPlayer
             */
            mSurface = new SurfaceTexture(mTextureID);
            mSurface.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);

            Surface surface = new Surface(mSurface);
            mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
            mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
            surface.release();

            try {
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "media player prepare failed");
            }

            synchronized(this) {
                updateSurface = false;
            }

            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }

        synchronized public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            updateSurface = true;
        }

        private int loadShader(int shaderType, String source) {
            int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType);
            if (shader != 0) {
                GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source);
                GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
                int[] compiled = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
                if (compiled[0] == 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not compile shader " + shaderType + ":");
                    Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
                    GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
                    shader = 0;
                }
            }
            return shader;
        }

        private int createProgram(String vertexSource, String fragmentSource) {
            int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
            if (vertexShader == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            int pixelShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource);
            if (pixelShader == 0) {
                return 0;
            }

            int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
            if (program != 0) {
                GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
                checkGlError("glAttachShader");
                GLES20.glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
                checkGlError("glAttachShader");
                GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
                int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
                if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not link program: ");
                    Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
                    GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program);
                    program = 0;
                }
            }
            return program;
        }

        private void checkGlError(String op) {
            int error;
            while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
                Log.e(TAG, op + ": glError " + error);
                throw new RuntimeException(op + ": glError " + error);
            }
        }

    }  // End of class VideoRender.

}  // End of class VideoSurfaceView.
```

And Here is my MainActivity

```
package me.crossle.demo.surfacetexture;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    protected Resources mResources;

    private VideoSurfaceView mVideoView = null;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mResources = getResources();
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            File dir = Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

            File file = new File(dir,
                    "video.mp4");
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        mVideoView = new VideoSurfaceView(this, mMediaPlayer);
        setContentView(mVideoView);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mVideoView.onResume();
    }
}
```

Comment: uploading a demo will help analyzing your issue.

Comment: Thats the whole code. I just need to know where i can apply effects in the whole code

Comment: I think you have to modify the fragment shader to achieve effects on the video. Try adding some value in this line
 "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord) + <add some float>;\n"

To understand the whole thing you need some understanding of Fragment and Vertex shaders.

Comment: @Lunero that just changes the contrast of the whole Video. Adding a float increases contrast and subtracting a float reduces contrast. I want to know how to apply effects on video if possible

Comment: @SherazAhmadKhilji yes this is the effect of this. You can read the texture color value of the neighbour pixels and calculate on these values some effects. Just as I said, have a look at OpenGl Fragment Shaders. But you might only use the media effects.
Then I have found this solution. At the link for the image shader it is also explained that you have to assign the filter to the onDrawFrame method, at the End! of this function.

Comment: Is your question "how can I apply effects to video", or specifically "how can I apply EffectFactory effects to video"?  For example, this demonstrates a convolution filter in a fragment shader: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg

Comment: @fadden i am specifically aiming to apply EffectFactory effects  on video because they have said in the documentation that its possible but if their is some other way to achieve those effects then i am open to suggestions :)

Comment: @Lunero which link are you referring to ?

Comment: The documentation for Effect shows it being applied to a GLES texture. You would need to send the video output to a SurfaceTexture, execute the Effect on that texture, and then render the texture for display. You could, for example, take the "texture from Camera" activity from Grafika and add the Effect to `draw()`. https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/TextureFromCameraActivity.java

Comment: @fadden i am a noob when it comes to Open Gl. Can you refer me some tutorials so that i can implement what you have suggested above ?
When you say `draw()` then which method are you referring to in `VideoSurfaceView` ?

Comment: @SherazAhmadKhilji I meant this [http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-android-media-effects-with-opengl-es--cms-23650](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-android-media-effects-with-opengl-es--cms-23650)

Comment: @fadden how to save this videos in sdcard after apply effect?

Comment: @SherazAhmadKhilji how to save this videos in sdcard after apply effect?

Comment: @MayankSugandhi That hasn't been implemented in the library yet but theoretically you could write the texture to a file and save it anywhere. You would have to do some R&D on that.

Comment: @SherazAhmadKhilji can you help me that which effect introduced by you , could you give me ffmpeg command of this effects? because as a view i show you effects and for saving i use to ffmpeg commands, but i dint get your effects command in FFMPEG..

Comment: I am using shaders and manipulating texture to apply effect and the source code is available on Github. i am not using FFMPEG for effects but you could find similar effects in FFMPEG and apply them,

Comment: How to blur and greyscale effect both at the same time? Is it possible to apply 2 effects at same time?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I have solved the issue and i am posting the answer in case anyone else is also looking for a way to apply different Filters on their video.

After being pointed out in the right direction by [Lunero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805837/applying-effects-on-video-being-played#comment51543141_31805837) and [Fadden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805837/applying-effects-on-video-being-played#comment51571387_31805837) i am now able to apply almost all [EffectFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html) effects to the video being played. Though these effects are only meant for **preview purpose** and **do not change the original video** but still they do the job for me.

What i did was that I changed the `FragmentShaders` code that was applied to the video being rendered and i was able to achieve different effects.

Here is the code for some `fragmentShaders`.

**Black and White Effect**

```
String fragmentShader = "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n"
                + "precision mediump float;\n"
                + "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n"
                + "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" 
                + "void main() {\n"
                + "  vec4 color = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n"
                + "  float colorR = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;\n"
                + "  float colorG = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;\n"
                + "  float colorB = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;\n"
                + "  gl_FragColor = vec4(colorR, colorG, colorB, color.a);\n"
                + "}\n";
```

**Negative Effect**

```
String fragmentShader = "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n"
                + "precision mediump float;\n"
                + "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n"
                + "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n"
                + "void main() {\n"
                + "  vec4 color = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n"
                + "  float colorR = (1.0 - color.r) / 1.0;\n"
                + "  float colorG = (1.0 - color.g) / 1.0;\n"
                + "  float colorB = (1.0 - color.b) / 1.0;\n"
                + "  gl_FragColor = vec4(colorR, colorG, colorB, color.a);\n"
                + "}\n";
```

**Original Video without any Effect**

[image]

**Video with Black and White Effect**

[image: Black and White Effect]

**Video with Negative Effect**

[image: Negative Effect]

If you like to apply more effects then i suggest you look at [VidEffects](https://github.com/krazykira/VidEffects) on github. It will help you apply many different effects on your video.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea on how your code might be altered to apply multiple shaders in succession?

Comment: @Michael One way to do it would be by calling the `mVideoView.init(mMediaPlayer,new DuotoneEffect(Color.YELLOW, Color.RED));` method whenever you want to change effects.

Comment: @SherazAhmadKhilji how to save this videos in sdcard after apply effect?

Comment: @MayankSugandhi, any success for saving video?It will help me too.

Comment: @SherazAhmadKhilji, any success for saving video?It will help me too.

Comment: how to save video after applying effects?

Comment: How to save and Share Video in sdcard after apply effect?

Comment: another person needing to save the video. we've seen the FBO from the graphika, but not sure it makes sense

Comment: any 1 get effect expect sepia and grayscale for video filters?

Comment: How to blur and greyscale effect both at the same time? Is it possible to apply 2 effects at same time?