# How to "apply fragment shader to GLSurfaceView/TextureView"?

Tags: android, opengl-es, exoplayer

**My goal is to have ExoPlayer display a color video as black and white.**

According to this [this Github issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1279) I should be able to achieve this with Open GL:

> ExoPlayer will render video to any Surface. You could use
>   SurfaceTexture, at which point you'd have video rendered into an
>   OpenGL ES texture. Once you have that you can do anything that OpenGL
>   lets you do, including using a pixel shader to transform the video to
>   black and white.

In [an older, but related, discussion in the Android Developers Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/U5RXFGpAHPE) Romain Guy gives some details as to how this should be done:

> - Create an OpenGL context
> - Generate an OpenGL texture name
> - Create a SurfaceTexture with the texture name
> - Pass the SurfaceTexture to Camera
> - Listen for updates On SurfaceTexture update, draw the texture with
>     OpenGL using the shader you want
>
> Simple :)

And by playing around with [Google's Cardboard example project](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java) I have determined that a fragment shader like the following one should be about right:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 v_Color;

void main() {
    float grayscale = v_Color[0] * 0.3 + v_Color[1] * 0.59 + v_Color[2] * 0.11;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(grayscale, grayscale, grayscale, 0.1);
}
```

I am also managed to have ExoPlayer render into a `TextureView` instead of the usual `SurfaceView`:

```
mPlayer.sendMessage(
    videoRenderer,
    MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_SURFACE,
    new Surface(mVideoTextureView.getSurfaceTexture())
);
```

***Now, how do I wire everything together?***

Where can I "apply" the shader to the `TextureView`? Is that even possible or should I use a `GLSurfaceView` instead? What would I need to do in the `Renderer`?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1220 and the link within it?

Comment: Thanks, the linked blog post did indeed provide a working solution! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey david, I am also trying to do the same thing but I'm stuck on this for the past 2 days. I took a look at the VidEffect's VideoSurfaceView code but when I integrate exoplayer the video is rendered black but with audio. If you still have the working solution, it would mean a lot if you can share that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have applied fragment shaders to a video being played by an ExoPlayer before. The most effective way seems to be to play the video onto a `GLSurfaceView`, since they have good support for custom renderers.

A working example of applying OpenGL shaders to a `GLSurfaceView` is available from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805837/applying-effects-on-video-being-played). It even has a greyscale fragment shader already as part of its [effects library](https://github.com/krazykira/VidEffects/blob/master/Vid%20Effects%20Library/src/com/sherazkhilji/videffect/GreyScaleEffect.java). The existing code will require some minor refactoring since it uses a `MediaPlayer` rather than an `ExoPlayer`.

Comment: Thanks! I built my solution from the blog post that @Morrison Chang's comment led me to - it uses a `TextureView` and passes the `Surface` to the ExoPlayer. But maybe I'll still have switch to `GLSurfaceView` because I'll also need to support VisualOn and that player only accepts a `SurfaceView` (not a `Surface` directly).