# Android/Nativescript - Applying a shader effect to a playing video

Tags: android, video, nativescript, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

In a NativeScript application, I'm trying to apply a real-time effect to an applied video (specifically, grayscale video playback). I am currently playing the video in app using a fork of the `nativescript-videoplayer` nativescript plugin. The relevant source code that creates the video view in android is here:

https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-videoplayer/blob/master/src/videoplayer.android.ts

In essence, I want to modify it to apply an effect / shader, similar to the answer given here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31958741/192694

However, I'm not sure where this shader code would hook up to my existing stream of `MediaPlayer` creation and setting its SurfaceTexture surface.

Comment: This is probably going to help I hope: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805837/applying-effects-on-video-being-played?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Treewallie thanks, yeah that is the SO question I linked to in my original post here, and I _think_ that is what I want.. however from the answer I can not determine how that would fit into my NativeScript app code.

Answer (score 2):

The original video player plugin uses a [TextureView](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-videoplayer/blob/master/src/videoplayer.android.ts#L524) on MediaPlayer instance, instead you may use the [GLSurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView) as showcased in the other SO example @Bill linked.